Is there any way to define optional parameters "growable" in Dart?
The default value of an optional parameter must be constant.
class DirectoryTree {
  final Directory directory;
  final List<DirectoryTree> children;

  const DirectoryTree({
    required this.directory,
    this.children = List.empty(growable: true),
  });
}

Is there any way to define optional parameters "growable" in Dart?

The typical way to have non-constant default arguments is to make the default value a constant sentinel value and to initialize it to the non-constant value you want later.  However, if you want DirectoryTree to have a const constructor then it will not be possible to have a growable List member since growable Lists are inherently non-constant.

@jamesdlin How would you replace the constant sentinel value? would you look at the length of the list?

Do you mean how would you check for a constant sentinel value?  Depends on what it is. null is usually a good sentinel value, so you'd just check children == null.

You could make the children optional like this
class DirectoryTree {
  final Directory directory;
  final List<DirectoryTree> children;

  const DirectoryTree({
    required this.directory,
    List<DirectoryTree>? children,
  }) : children = children ??[];


const [] is not growable from my understanding. you can't add things to that list, right?

yeah const is immutable.... if you want it to be mutable, then we could remove const and make it []
